# Scale Size of Sortable Element on drag JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scale, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to scale down/up my image/div when dragging an item in a sortable jQuery UI

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdhulster/sr5QM/) almost shows what I want instead I want to resize the image in percentages so it scales the image up or down relative to it's own size for 50% for example.

```
$(".icon").draggable({
start: function() {
    $(this).height(100).width(100);
},
stop: function() {
    $(this).height(50).width(50);        
}
```

});

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean that it scales up/down 50%? Relative to what? Their own size? Size of any container?

This shows how to get it to scale up/down relative to its own size. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sr5QM/1/)

Changes are made to script:

```
$(".icon").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $(this).height($(this).height()+ ($(this).height()/2)).width($(this).width()+ ($(this).width()/2));
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).height($(this).height() - ($(this).height()/3)).width($(this).width() - ($(this).width()/3));
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I meant relative to it's own size , I edited the post! Thanks! I'll try that out